# Cannot store data to session

Tags: php, session

I cant carry my session throughout files.

I checked

- I have session_start() at the beginning of each file
- Used notepad, so no unseen BOM characters added by IDE
- No error, warning etc.
- Sessions are enabled (see phpinfo() output below )
- No rewrites etc.

So my files are as follows

a.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["test"] = "value";
header("Location: b.php");
exit;
```

b.php

```
session_start();
echo "session: ";
print_r($_SESSION);
```

output of `b.php`:

```
session: Array ()
```

`phpinfo()` output:

[image]

(Also `session_id()` is same in both files, and I have a session cookie file.)

Only thing I can think of is session save path may not have write permission, but this is a shared host, so I assume this is not the case (I'll check with the host porvider anyway)

What am I missing here?

Comment: sorry, forgot to say that: 5.3.6

Answer (score 0):

on page b.php

use this code

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["test"];
```

instead of

```
session_start();
echo "session: ";
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: in that code you are not print the session variable 
 your a printing echo "session:";

that can be a word or string

Comment: echo "session: " is just an expression to see the output, it's not important. Important part is print_r($_SESSION) which outputs an empty array. And also echo $_SESSION["test"] is an empty string as well

Comment: `print_r` prints the whole `$_SESSSION`. isn't it enough?